# Sublime Text 2 Package Control Can't Install Packages because of SSL problems

Tags: git, sublimetext2

I'm running Sublime Text 2 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit and when I tried to Install a package, the following error prompts up:

```
Package Control: There are no packages available for installation
```

And this error appears in the console:

```
Package Control: Error submitting usage information. URL error _ssl.c:480: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/submit?package_control_version=1.5.0&sublime_platform=windows&package=Package+Control&sublime_version=2217&version=1.5.0&operation=install.
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2012-08-16 16:40:50, next run at 2012-08-16 17:40:50 or after
```

Package Control worked on the exact same network and computer before, the only thing different is that this is a new system I installed in a partition.

I have no proxy running whatsoever; tried it with firewall turned off, still the same results.

Also, I was git cloning some repos in Windows Command Line, and there's an SSL error as well. So I searched it up on the Internet and by turning SSL verify off using the following command solves it, But Sublime Text 2 still can't get through the SSL verification thing.

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Could someone please help me solve this problem. Life's so much harder without Package Control.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. And it's automatically synced. I think the problem has to do with SSL verify